# Questions regarding the sequence $f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2},\ \ \ \ \ x\in[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

> Define a function $f_n:[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ by
>   $$f_n(x)=\frac{x^2}{x^2+(1-nx)^2},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x\in[0,1]$$
>   I am asked three questions:
>
> (a) show that the sequence $(f_n)$ is uniformly bounded, i.e., $|f_n(x)|\leq M$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $n\in \mathbb{N}$.
>
> (b) determine the pointwise limit of $(f_n)$.
>
> (c) show that $(f_n)$ contains no uniformly converging subsequences.

My workings:

(a) Obviously the numerator is smaller or equal to one. So I thought if we could find a lower bound for the denominator $x^2+(1-nx)^2 \geq L$ for some $L$ then $f_n\leq \frac{1}{L}$ for all $n$ and $x\in[0,1]$. I cannot seem to find this lower limit though.

(b) When $x=0$ it is obvious to see that $f_n(0)=0$. When $0<x<1$. I would think that $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f_n=0$ because the magnitude of the denominator keeps growing while the numerator stays the same. I cant seem to figure it out fully thought, similarly for the case $x=1$. I think the sequence should converge to a function that equals 0 where $0\leq x <1$ and that it is $1$ when $x=1$.

(c) I really dont know, if my hypothesis about the pointwise limit in question (b) is true I would be inclined to say that because the sequence converges point wise to a discontinuous function, no subsequence can exist that converges uniformly.

I realize it's a very long question and I didn't get far at all. Some help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: (a) Note the numerator is no  larger than the denominator, and that both are nonnegative. (b) The pointwise limit is the zero function (everywhere). (c) What is $f_n(1/n)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For part (a):

There is no lower bound for the denominator that proves useful. However, note $f_n$ has the form $A\over A+B$ where both $A$ and $B$ are nonnegative. As such, you have $0\le f_n(x)\le 1$ for all $n$ and all $x$ ($0\le{A\over A+B}\le{A+B\over A+B}=1$).

For part (b):

For exactly the reasons you mention, $(f_n(x))$ converges pointwise to the zero function for *every* $x$ in $[0,1]$ (in particular, for $x=1$, the numerator is constant while the denominator tends to $\infty$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$).

For part (c):

You can't unfortunately use the argument you provide in your question, as the limit function is continuous. However, if you compute $f_n(1/n)$ for each positive integer $n$, you should be able to see why the convergence can't be uniform on $[0,1]$ (or indeed on any nondegenerate interval containing $0$ or having $0$ as an endpoint).

---

Towards examining the convergence properties of a sequence of functions, 
it's usually a good idea to examine the graphs of the functions. Below are shown the graphs of
$
\color{maroon}{f_1},
\color{darkblue}{f_2},
\color{darkgreen}{f_4},
\color{pink}{f_8},
\color{cyan}{f_{16}},
\color{yellow}{f_{32}}
$

[image]

Looking at these graphs, the method I suggest for part (c) shouldn't seem mysterious.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! unfortunately It all seems so obvious when someone spells it out but is difficult to do on your own. Thanks!

Comment: @TeunVerstraaten You're welcome. Glad to help.

Comment: Sorry for pushing up an old thread, just wondering how does considering $f(\frac{1}{n})$ allow us to determine if it converges uniformly or not?

Comment: @Natash1 $f_n(1/n)=1$ for all $n$. The sequence, thus, can't converge uniformly to the zero function on $[0,1]$ (if it did, eventually, $|f_n(x)|<1/2$ for all $n$ and all $x$).